# Git fatal: ambiguous argument unknown revision with two dots rev spec when names contain docs too

Tags: git

```
$ git log v1.10.0..v.11.0
fatal: ambiguous argument 'v1.10.0..v.11.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

$ git log v1.10.0..v.11.0 --
fatal: bad revision 'v1.10.0..v.11.0'
```

On other hand following works:

```
$ git log master..develop
```

How can I quote dots in revset specs?

Comment: Looks like you typo'd `v1.10.0..v1.11.0`, see the difference?

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are the exact references in your `A..B` expression here?

Comment: Sorry, I can't spot typo for half hour ((

Comment: Please explain closer what you want help with. Do you have a tag or a branch actually named "v1.10.0..v.11.0"? Or is that an `A..B` expression? If so what is `A` and what is `B`?

Comment: I have never, ever been that blind. You believe me, don't you? :-)

Comment: couldn't spot originally but got with answer below. Please close  it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the `1` in the second version, resulting in an invalid tag/branch name that git doesn't recognize.

```
$ git log v1.10.0..v1.11.0
# Was missing ------^
```